# 外部ファイルの読み込み完了判定をしたい

Tags: javascript

HTML側で下記のような構造だったとします。

```
<head>
    ～
    <script src="A.js">
</head>
<body>
    ～
    <script src="B.js">
</body>
```

「A.js」は具体的にはGoogleAnalyticsの解析タグで、便宜的に「A.js」と書きます。
ここで宣言されているga関数を「B.js」で使いたく考えています。

読み込む順序的にbody側に記述すれば行けるかなと思ったのですが、Chromeでは数回に1回、IEではほぼ毎回「A.js」より前に「B.js」のロードが完了しエラーが返されます。

「A.js」には手を出せず、HTML本体も「B.js」をロードする以外は手を出すことができない状態で、「B.js」側で「A.js」がHTMLで読み込みが完了しているかどうかを判定する方法があればご教示頂ければと思います。

Comment: scriptタグはasyncやdeferを指定しない限り書かれた順番に実行されることが保証されています。何か別の問題があるのでは。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
私もそれを想定していたのですが、Chromeでは順番通りにロードされ実行されるのですが、IEではほぼ必ずB.jsのロードが先に完了して実行されてしまうため対処が必要になりました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

普通の関数(`ga`)が定義済みかどうかだったら、`window.ga == undefined`が真ならまだ読み込まれていない(falseなら既に読み込まれている)と判断できると思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
こちらの方法でうまく行きそうなため試したく思います。

Answer (score 1):

今のGoogle Analyticsのコードの場合、< script>タグ内でga関数を定義し終えてしまうため、質問のような現象にはならないはずですが。
[JavaScript Snippet Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#snippetReference)より（i=window、r="ga"です。）

```
// Creates an initial ga() function.  The queued commands will be executed once analytics.js loads.
i[r] = i[r] || function() {
  (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
},
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。BLUEPIXYさんの方法でひとまず試したく思います。